# jQuery: check the type of SVG element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

How can I check the type of an svg object in JavaScript or jQuery?
I want to check whether a tag is of type `SVGAnimatedString`.

When I output the object to the console it outputs the following:

```
console.log(this.href);
SVGAnimatedString // is an object and can be expanded
```

In my code I try to check whether it is a SVG object but the check does not work.

```
if (this.href == 'SVGAnimatedString'){ //this check does not work
     //it s an svg object
    var url = this.href.animVal
}
else{
    var url = this.href; //get the href from the <a> element
}
```

How do I correctly check whether it is a `SVGAnimatedString` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not compare the types using `==`. You need to use `instanceof`. You can do this way:

```
if (this.href instanceof SVGAnimatedString){ //this check works!!!
     //it s an svg object
    var url = this.href.animVal
}
else{
    var url = this.href; //get the href from the <a> element
}
```

The [`SVGAnimatedString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/SVGAnimatedString) has less browser support. Keep that in mind. :)

Comment: Thanks it works now. Regarding browser compatibility: I only want to check the type, since the SVGAnimatedString object is returned from an svg object I created with D3. I tested it with Chrome and FF, and it works. Do you think I will run into issues using other browsers?

Comment: That should work, you could probably also use something like `if ('animVal' in this.href)`